# detect when 2 calendar values changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making a financial report where user choose 2 dates `search_date1` and `search_date2`, and then a monthly report is generated.

I created first a daily report with only one calendar and when it is changed I apply some AJAX script to it and it works correctly:

```
var myApp = {};
myApp.search_date = "";
 document.getElementById('search_date').onchange = function (e) {
    if (this.value != myApp.search_date) {
        var d = $("#search_date").val();
    $.ajax({
        ...
    });
  }
}
```

Now I can't know how to detect if both calendars are changed to apply AJAX script according to their values.

**EDIT**

Is it correct to do the following:

```
var myApp = {};
myApp.search_date1 = "";
myApp.search_date2 = "";
 document.getElementById('search_date1').onchange = function (e) {
    if (this.value != myApp.search_date1) {
        var d1 = $("#search_date1").val();
        document.getElementById('search_date2').onchange = function (e) {
             if (this.value != myApp.search_date2) {
                     var d2 = $("#search_date2").val();
                     $.ajax({
                        ...
                     })
             }
         });
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```js
var temp = {
  from: null,
  to: null
}

document.getElementById('from').onchange = function(e){
  
 temp.from = e.target.value;
  goAjax();
}
document.getElementById('to').onchange = function(e){
 temp.to = e.target.value;
  goAjax();
}

function goAjax(){
  if(temp.from && temp.to && new Date(temp.from) < new Date(temp.to)){
    //do ajax call
    console.log('valid')
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id='from'/>
<br>
<input type="date" id='to'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you do in your edit may work, but it would be better (and easier) do something like this

```
var myApp = {};
myApp.original_search_date1 = $("#search_date1").val();
myApp.original_search_date2 = $("#search_date2").val();
myApp.search_date1 = $("#search_date1").val();
myApp.search_date2 = $("#search_date2").val();

document.getElementById('search_date1').onchange = function (e) {
    if ($("#search_date1").val() != myApp.search_date1) {
        myApp.search_date1 = $("#search_date1").val();
        sendAjax();
    }
});

document.getElementById('search_date2').onchange = function (e) {
    if ($("#search_date2").val() != myApp.search_date2) {
        myApp.search_date2 = $("#search_date2").val();
        sendAjax();
     }
});

function sendAjax() {
    if (myApp.original_search_date1 !== myApp.search_date1 &&
        myApp.original_search_date2 !== myApp.search_date2) {
        $.ajax({
            ...
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have captured the change event for both elements :

```
$("#search_date1, #search_date2").on('change',function(){
    var d1 = $("#search_date1").val();
    var d2 = $("#search_date2").val();
    $.ajax({...});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Cant you just set a variable to check if its been changed with true/false then run the script if both variables are true.

Something like,

```
     var searchOneToggled = false, 
         searchTwoToggled = false;

     $('#search_date_one').on('input', function() {
         searchOneToggled = true;
         runYourFunction();
     });

     $('#search_date_two').on('input', function() {
         searchTwoToggled = true;
         runYourFunction();
     });

     function runYourFunction() {
         if(searchOneToggled === true && searchTwoToggled === true) {
            alert('hello world');
         }
     }
```